# XSD Combination of Choice

Tags: xml, xsd

What is the correct way of adding combination of "choice" elements to an xsd.

For example, if choices available where (And only 1 of the following allowed):

- Cell Number
- Cell Number AND Home Number
- Home Number AND Work Number

Below is the XSD that I have tried, but error received when generating is:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/thefile.xsd; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 25; cos-nonambig: "namespace":CellNumber and "namespace":CellNumber (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema ...>
    <xs:element name="AddNewPersonRequestMessage">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                ...
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:group ref="group1" />
                    <xs:group ref="group2" />
                    <xs:group ref="group3" />
                </xs:choice>
                ..
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="WorkNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
    <xs:element name="CellNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
    <xs:element name="HomeNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
    <xs:group name="group1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="CellNumber" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="group2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="WorkNumber" />
            <xs:element ref="HomeNumber" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:group name="group3">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="CellNumber" />
            <xs:element ref="HomeNumber" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the [**Unique Particle Attribution**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig) violation by rearranging your logic.

Observe that the disjunction of

- Cell Number
- Cell Number AND Home Number

can be rewritten as

- Cell Number AND ***optional*** Home Number

and rewrite your XSD as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="AddNewPersonRequestMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:group ref="group2" />
          <xs:group ref="group3" />
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="WorkNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
  <xs:element name="CellNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
  <xs:element name="HomeNumber" type="xs:unsignedInt" />

  <xs:group name="group2">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="WorkNumber" />
      <xs:element ref="HomeNumber" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:group name="group3">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="CellNumber"/>
      <xs:element ref="HomeNumber"  minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
</xs:schema>
```

and you will have an equivalent form that does not violate Unique Particle Attribution.